# Why is this insert statement throwing an expression missing error?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I am using Oracle SQL. Why is this insert statement throwing an expression missing error?

```
INSERT INTO T_DATA(id, object_type, object_id, 
                         measurement_id, derived_ind, no_hist_ind,
                         display_order, stored_precision, display_precision,
                         required_ind, mod_user, mod_dtime)
                  VALUES(SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM t_data_point, 'Object', 'ObjectName', 
                        'ID', 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 'TEST', SYSDATE);
```

Comment: the `select` part of `VALUES` isn't being treated as the corresponding data type i guess

Comment: Do ***NOT*** use `SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM ` to generate unique IDs. Use a sequence, everything else **is** going to break - rather sooner than later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your usage can be just `INSERT.. INTO.. SELECT..`

```
INSERT INTO T_DATA(id, object_type, object_id, 
                         measurement_id, derived_ind, no_hist_ind,
                         display_order, stored_precision, display_precision,
                         required_ind, mod_user, mod_dtime)
                  (SELECT MAX(id) + 1,  'Object', 'ObjectName', 
                        'ID', 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 'TEST', SYSDATE
                         FROM t_data_point);
```

To use the `SELECT` inside `VALUES`... embed them in brackets.

```
VALUES(
       (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM t_data_point),
       ...
      )
```

**EDIT:**

Make sure, the expression in `INSERT` columns and `VALUES` match.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative to MahMaheswaran's answer. You can still achieve the query whilst using VALUES. You just needed to wrap the SELECT statement in parenthesis.

```
INSERT INTO T_DATA (Id,
    object_type,
    object_id,
    measurement_id,
    derived_ind,
    no_hist_ind,
    display_order,
    stored_precision,
    display_precision,
    required_ind,
    mod_user,
    mod_dtime)
    VALUES (
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(Id) + 1
        FROM t_data_point
    )
    ,
    'Object',
    'ObjectName',
    'ID',
    3,
    0,
    1,
    2,
    2,
    0,
    'TEST',
    SYSDATE);
```

However, I would still use the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

it would seem the data you provided is less in amount of data that is required for insertion.

insert into t_data(12 expressions) VALUES (11 expressions)